# Search for the first character in the line

Tags: notepad++

I have a php.ini file, similar to the following example:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Language Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Enable the PHP scripting language engine under Apache.
; http://php.net/engine
engine = On
```

I need to search and select all lines that have no semicolon ";" as the first character

Comment: ^[^;].* would be a regex expression

Comment: @RonTrunk that's a valid answer. Why don't you write up an answer? That way it can be marked as answered and earns you reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression (regex):

```
^[^;].*
```

to select lines without semicolons as the first character.